# How to count by the value of a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table called `votes`, and a column in that table called `vote_type` which can either be 0 or 1. How can I fetch the `COUNT` of `vote_type` where `vote_type` is `1`?

Right now, I can select the count of `vote_type` overall, but not the count of `vote_type` where it is 1 or 0, via this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(votes.vote_id) AS vote_count
    FROM votes 
    WHERE <some condition>
    ORDER BY vote_count
```

How can I select the total number of vote_types, the number of vote_types = 1, the number of vote_types = 0, and the total vote_value (votetypes = 1 minus votetypes = 0), and order it by the total vote_value?

EDIT: Note that 1 & 0 are not intrinsic values of a vote, but boolean expressions for a positive vote and a negative vote.

Comment: What means `total vote_value (votetypes = 1 minus votetypes = 0)` ?

Comment: @Tim total_vote_value is equivalent to the net overall score, so the number of positive votes (vote_type = 1), subtracted by the number of negative votes (vote_type = 0).

Comment: What database are you using ? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Oracle? Other?

Comment: @Prix: MySQL, InnoDB. If that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) TotalVotes,
        SUM(CASE WHEN vote_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalVoteOne,
        SUM(CASE WHEN vote_type = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalVoteZero,
        SUM(CASE WHEN vote_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
        SUM(CASE WHEN vote_type = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalVoteValue
FROM    votes
-- WHERE    ....
-- ORDER    ....
```

When you say *order it by the total vote_value* -- it actually doesn't makes sense since the total number of rows in the result is only one.

You can also wrap this in a subquery,

```
SELECT  TotalVotes,
        TotalVoteOne, 
        TotalVoteZero,
        (TotalVoteOne - TotalVoteZero) AS TotalVoteValue
FROM
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*) TotalVotes,
            SUM(CASE WHEN vote_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalVoteOne,
            SUM(CASE WHEN vote_type = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalVoteZero
    FROM    tableName
    -- WHERE    ....
    -- ORDER    BY TotalVoteValue DESC
) a
```

Comment: Thank you. Needed to learn up about subqueries, but I got there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly are you trying to do, but if you want to count all the votes with Vote_Type=1
try

```
SELECT COUNT(votes.vote_id) AS vote_count
FROM votes 
WHERE votes.vote_type=1
```

or if you need to sum the votes

```
SELECT SUM(votes.vote_type) AS vote_sum
FROM votes 
WHERE votes.vote_type=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to start with something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN votetype = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS vote_count_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN votetype = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS vote_count_0
    FROM votes 
    WHERE <some condition>
    ORDER BY vote_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Added a `net_vote` column, which I think is the "`vote1 minus vote0`" number you are after.

```
Select
    Sum(Case v.vote_type When 1 then 1 else -1 end) as net_vote
From
    Votes v
Where
    <some condition>
```

I've removed the `order by`, because this is only going to return one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT *FROM  votes  WHERE vote_type=1 || vote_type=0";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$WhereVoteIsOne=$row['vote_type'];

foreach ($WhereVoteIsOne as $votesCount) { echo $votesCount."<br/>";}
```